# How can I omit case class fields in a slick table mapping?

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I'm teaching myself some Scala and am currently getting my feet wet with slick (3.1) + play framework, so maybe the answer is simple here and I'm missing something obvious. I have the following model and Table

```
case class User(id: Long = -1,
                username: String,
                passwordHash: String,
                email: Option[String] = None) 

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def username = column[String]("USERNAME")
    def email = column[Option[String]]("EMAIL")
    def passwordHash = column[String]("PASSWD_HASH")
    def * = (id, username, passwordHash, email) <>((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
  }
```

Now this above works just fine as it is, but I'd like to add some fields to the `User` case class that *aren't* saved in the USER table, namely permissions and roles, like this:

```
case class User(id: Long = -1,
                username: String,
                passwordHash: String,
                email: Option[String] = None,
                permissions: Seq[String] = Seq.empty,
                roles: Seq[String] = Seq.empty)
```

Those are supposed to go into their own respective tables as userid -> permission/role mappings (simple one to many relationships).

Ultimately those should be queried too, but for now I'd just like to ignore the additional fields (purely as an exercise). How do I adjust the original projection in the table to omit/ignore those new fields? Obviously the original mapping

```
 def * = (id, username, passwordHash, email) <>((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
```

doesn't work anymore since the touple doesnt match the case class. As far as I can tell it shouldnt be too hard since `<>` just takes two functions that convert from a touple to a User instance and vice versa and those functions should just ignore the new fields (or fill them with their default values). But I can't figure out how to express that.

I tried adding a new `apply()` with a shorter signature to the `User` companion object, but then I get an error that basically tells me that slick doesnt know which `apply()` to use. Makes sense, but I dont know how to reference one or the other. I did the same thing with an additional constructor for `User`, the result is the same problem. And I tried writing basic conversion functions like this:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

    def constructUser = (id: Long, username: String, passwordHash: String, email: Option[String]) =>
      User(id, username, passwordHash, email)

    def extractUser = (user: User) => user match {
      case User(id, username, passwordHash, email, permissions, roles) =>
        Some((id, username, passwordHash, email))
    }

    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def username = column[String]("USERNAME")
    def email = column[Option[String]]("EMAIL")
    def passwordHash = column[String]("PASSWD_HASH")
    def * = (id, username, passwordHash, email) <>(constructUser, extractUser)
  }
```

Sadly that also leads to an error:

```
[error]  found   : (Long, String, String, Option[String]) => models.User
[error]  required: ? => ?
[error]     def * = (id, username, passwordHash, email) <>(constructUser, deconstructUser)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your trouble here is your `constructUser` is function of 4 parameters, while it supposed to be function of single `Tuple4`

Try to add type signatures.
This sample works for instance ( some simplifications included )

```
type Data = (Long, String, String, Option[String])

def constructUser: Data => User = {
  case (id, username, passwordHash, email) => User(id, username, passwordHash, email)

}
def extractUser: PartialFunction[User, Data] = {
  case User(id, username, passwordHash, email, _, _) =>
    (id, username, passwordHash, email)
}

def * = (id, username, passwordHash, email) <> (constructUser, extractUser.lift)
```

Comment: That works and makes perfect sense. Thank you. Sadly I can't upvote yet. :)

Comment: @Odomontois Thanks. The answer works for me too in the above scenario(i.e - add some fields to the User case class that aren't saved in the USER table). But In my case(For example), I have added the another table as a field in the USER table. Instead of "permissions, roles" I have added "accessToken: Option[AccessToken] = None" and "oauthClient: Option[Client] = None". But I want to map those values. How Do I do? Can you please check the below question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37183156/1584121

Comment: @Odomontois, thank you, this was very helpful! I just wanted to add that this strategy (well, you'll have to change this code a little bit) can be used to eliminate the mismatch between case classes and tables the other way around (that's what I did): if your case classes have fewer fields than rows in the table (for instance, if you don't have an id in your case class). All other techniques I googled were much harder. Thanks again!